# How to use navigation stack in catkin workspace?

Tags: navigation, catkin, actionlib, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey folks,

I'd like to follow the simple goal sending tutorial but I can't compile my node because `catkin` can't find `move_base`. I understand that it's due to the fact that the `navigation` stack isn't catkinized yet.

But doesn't that mean that I cannot under any circumstances create a `move_base` goal sending node as long as I'm bound to a `catkin` workspace, at least unless I catkinize the `navigation` stack myself? I don't have the faintest idea on how to do that.

I'd appreciate any kind of help.

Cheers,
Hendrik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/72943/how-to-use-navigation-stack-in-catkin-workspace?/) by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1145 on 2013-08-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Navigation has been catkinized for Hydro. You can check out the latest source to your catkin workspace.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2013-08-14**:
Could you give me a little more detail on how I do that exactly? I'm still learning...

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-08-15**:
I see you have since asked this as another question, which has been answered. Is that sufficient? http://answers.ros.org/question/73102/need-some-advice-on-how-to-use-hydro-navigation-in-groovy/

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2013-08-15**:
Unfortunately not, but I think it's better to continue in the other thread. It's more specific... I'd happily see you take part in helping solving my problem. ;-)

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-08-16**:
I'll try, but William knows more about it than I do. Back-porting code to an earlier ROS version can be difficult. Is it possible for you to move up to Hydro, instead?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-08-16**:
Yeah, I have been trying to answer the less direct, more generic question of resolving dependencies in your workspace, but my recommendation for your particular problem would be to upgrade everything to Hydro. It will be much easier.

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2013-08-16**:
Yeah, that's planned for as soon as Hydro is officially released. We don't really have the courage to migrate before Hydro is considered stable. However I guess I'll give it a try in a backup environment.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-08-16**:
It's pretty stable now, for most uses.

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2013-08-16**:
Okay, I'll give it a try. Fingers crossed!